# Можно ли менять цвет SVG при добавлении в :after или :before?

Tags: html, css, svg

Можно ли менять цвет stroke и fill в SVG файле обращаясь к нему через CSS?
Допустим я подключил SVG вот так:

```
.mame:after {
  content: url(name.svg);
}
```

При наведении мне нужно что-бы менялся fill или stroke этого файла. Если добавлять SVG через HTML, это делается легко. Но можно ли сделать что-то такое:

```
.mame:hover.mame:after {
  fill: #484848;
}
```

Думаю сама идея бредовая, но вдруг есть какие-то способы.
Или второй вариант. Как мне добавить в after SVG элемент такого вида:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="23.001" height="22.999" viewBox="0 0 23.001 22.999">
  <path data-name="Объединение 6" d="M-9940,18V8h-10V5h10V-5h3V5h10V8h-10V18Z" transform="translate(9950.001 4.999)" fill="#EB653E"/>
</svg>
```

Так я легко смогу обратиться к fill и поменять цвет.

Comment: @Дмытрык Нет, не дубликат. В вопросе по вашей ссылке SVG добавлялся `<img>` Поэтому стилизация Была невозможна, только через фильтры CSS SVG

Comment: @Дмытрык нет и background нет | только `object`  и `iframe` позволяют менять стили

Comment: @Alexandr_TT,  Ну, так почему не дубликат? Только из-за того, что топик содержит 2 вопроса,а не 1?

Comment: @Дмытрык ну вы уже дали ссылку на свой топик, ещё что-то нужно?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, не)

Comment: @Дмытрык тем более, кто хотел уже проплюсовали там, давно за отличные ответы и я в том числе :)

Comment: @Дмытрык Не вижу в Вашем "возможном дубликате" ни намёка на мой вопрос. Хотелось бы получить ответ именно на МОЙ вопрос.

Comment: Сделайте полноценный элемент. Зачем специально мучаться и создавать какие-то костыли вокруг этого. Так можно хотеть в пробел вставить документ. Если уже скрипты пошли в ход (в ответе), то элемент можно воткнуть скриптом, если уж нужна чистота тега в темплейте.

Comment: Как вы решили свою проблему? У меня точно такая же. необходимо чтобы svg меняла свет при active и при hover. не знаю как это сделать.

Answer (score 2):

> Как мне добавить в after SVG элемент такого вида:

Легко и непринуждённо.

```css
#demo::before {
  content: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='23.001' height='22.999' viewBox='0 0 23.001 22.999'%3E%3Cpath data-name='Объединение 6' d='M-9940,18V8h-10V5h10V-5h3V5h10V8h-10V18Z' transform='translate(9950.001 4.999)' fill='%23EB653E'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Для этого давно уже заботливыми руками написан [правильный перекодировщик](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/).